# Angular 7 components: how to detect a change by user interaction?

Tags: html, angular, angular7, angular2-components

I have a component with several checkboxes, drop-downs, and a save button.
Here is a simplified example component template:

```html
<aside class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="all-users"
      [(ngModel)]="showAllUsers"
      (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
    />
    <label for="all-users">Show all users</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <ng-select
      [(ngModel)]="selectedUser"
      [clearable]="false"
      appendTo="body"
      (change)="onChange($event)"
    >
      <ng-option *ngFor="let user of activeUsers" [value]="user">{{ user }}</ng-option>
    </ng-select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!dirty" (click)="onSave()">
      Save Changes
    </button>
  </div>
</aside>
```

I want to enable the `Save Changes` button only when the user made a change, either by unchecking the check-box or changing a selection in drop-down box.

Right now I have an event handler registered at each and every control in the component (the `onChange` function in the example above), and use a `dirty` flag to disable or enable the `Save Changes` button.

Here is the component.ts for the above template:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {
  dirty: boolean;
  showAllUsers: boolean;
  selectedUser: string;
  activeUsers: string[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dirty = false;
    this.showAllUsers = true;
    this.activeUsers = ['Thanos', 'Thor', 'Starlord'];
    this.selectedUser = 'Thor';
  }
  onChange(event) {
    console.log('Event is ' + event);
    this.dirty = true;
  }
  onSave() {
    console.log('Gonna save changes...');
    this.dirty = false;
  }
}
```

Registering the event handler to every control does not seem intuitive to me.

Is this the correct approach to figure out a change made by user or does angular provide a different way to achieve this?

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl, with the `dirty` property

Comment: @Morphyish thank you. As you see the example, I do not use a form. I just placed the controls in the component. Do you suggest that I use reactive forms? (FormControl as well as https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup because I have several controls)?

Comment: That would be the easiest way to do it in my opinion, the dirty property is exactly what you are looking for and it would be easier than doing it from scratch.

Comment: Ok, will try it and let you know the result!

Comment: @Morphyish I took your hint and followed the angular reactive forms guide at https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms. Looks like it is a better approach than managing the `dirty` flag myself. Could you please elaborate your comment a bit and post it as an answer? I will accept the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would highly recommand using both [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) and [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) to achieve this behavior.

Both exposes the [dirty](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#dirty) property, a *read-only* boolean.

The `dirty` property is set to `true` when the user changes the value of the `FormControl` from the UI. In the case of the `FormGroup`, the dirty property is set to `true` as long as at least 1 of the `FormControl` in that group is dirty.

As a side note, the property `pristine` is the opposite property. So you can use one or the other if it simplifies the condition.

`[disabled]="myFormGroup.pristine"` might be easier to read than `[disabled]="!myFormGroup.dirty"`.